# Am I correct about these being subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

> I am self learning (today is my Day 1) Linear Algebra today using "Linear Algebra Done the Right way" and I have just finished the first chapter. Since the exercises don't have answers and I have no one to guide me (no teacher). I would really appreciate if anyone tells me if I have approached the questions correctly.

---

Question:

[image]

---

My attempt:

a) Yes, because if $x_1+2x_2+3x_3=0$ that means $x_1=0$, $x_2=0$, $x_3=0$ Therefore contains 0 vector. The addition and scalar is straight forward.

b) No. Because all $x_1,x_2,x_3$ won't have zero vector. So won't contain  the zero vector.

c) Sadly No idea, please help.

d) Yes because zero vector is there when $x_3=0$ and $x_2=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for (3): $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ both belong to that set, does their sum $(1,1,1)$ belong too?

Comment: (+1) Thank you very much :D No it doesn't belong (because 1(1)(1) is not 0 :D Can you also tell me whether Im correct with the other parts?

Comment: Explanations for (a) and (b) are complete, for (d) you may have to check (simple computation) addition and multiplication by scalar.

Comment: Checked :D it works for multiplication by scalar and addition. My final answer for (d) is yes it's a subspace. Am I correct ? :)

Comment: Correct, it is a subspace. In general anything of the form $\{(x_1,\cdots,x_N): \sum_{i=1}^N a_i x_i =0\}$ gives a subspace.

Comment: Thank you very much Milly. Means alot to me, the only support I have is MSE and Im so happy that so many people take their time to help me. Im very grateful to you Milly :)

Comment: You're welcome.